# I've pluged e-pci power cable(6+2pin) to eps 8 pin on motherboard

Tags: motherboard, eps

I've pluged e-pci power cable(6+2pin) to eps 8 pin on motherboard. There is no problem with connection Computer runs for few secunds and turn off and now don't start. Epci cable was warm. 
Now my question there's possible to repair that? Or motherboard is broken and only way is buy new one

Comment: Have you tried connecting the correct cable yet?

Comment: Yes, doesnt start anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a comparison of their pinouts (image taken from [Overclock.net: GPU and CPU power connections](http://www.overclock.net/a/gpu-and-cpu-power-connections)):

[image]

In theory you should not have been able to fit the connector. From the image above you can see that there are several keying differences between the pins (chamfered edges on the pins) that would have made it difficult to connect an EPS connector to a PCIe on a graphics card, but sadly probably not the other way around. This is something of an oversight in connector design.

The pinouts are effectively opposite. Where one PCIe has the 12V lines on 1-4 (ignoring sense pins), EPS has them on 5-8. What you have effectively managed to do is switch 12V and ground. Definitely not good.

Chances are you have blown out some or all of the power regulators on the motherboard, with possibly more components gone as well. There is nothing you can do without a lot of fault-finding and desoldering components.

Your board is fried. You need to get a new one. It is difficult to know whether your CPU or other components are fried without first replacing the motherboard.

Comment: I don't use force to connect that (the same force i use to connect 24pins), i think this is poor quality plastics. Pins with chamfered edges fits to squared one. On motherboard there's any sign of fry and on cpu.

Comment: The keying is quite poor. Afaict there are two keying features that differ between a PCIe 8 pin mini-fit and a regular 8 pin mini-fit (used for EPS). One pin is chamfered on the PCIe but not the regular which should stop you plugging a regular cable into a PCIe header but is no help the other way round. The other is a plastic connection between two pins on the cable connector to stop you pluging a PCIe 8 pin cable into a regular 8 pin socket, unfortunately in a 6+2 conncetor this plastic connection is split between the two parts of the connector dramatically reducing it's effectiveness.

Comment: Yeah, looking at it again the keying would prevent you connecting an EPS connector to a PCIe on a graphics card, but probably not the other way around.

Comment: @JakubRuść I've had another look and amended my answer regarding the keying.

Comment: Thanks, there is only hope that shop will not notice that  that motherboard is fry and accept warranty