# Can use these 3 8-pin connectors for my 3090?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building

I have an EVGA RTX 3090, and it has three 8-pin connectors to power it. On my PSU, it looks like it has enough connectors, but they are grouped weird, so I don't know if I can use them all.

Are all the 8-pins the same, and the cable is what is important? These are the 3 I was going to use, but I want to ask first.

- **Power supply**: [Corsair 850W Gold rated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079H5WNXN)
- **GPU**: EVGA FTW3 Ultra

[image: Power Suppply]

[image: GPU]

Comment: What about the connector on the card and the other end of the cable? You can also provide part numbers

Comment: I added another picture with model numbers

Comment: You need to be very, **very** sure that you have the right cables and connectors from those sockets and that you have the right power going in the right directions. The "4x4 CPU"  (EPS) and PCIe connectors have opposite power pins but are sadly all too easy to connect wrongly: https://superuser.com/questions/1281414/ive-pluged-e-pci-power-cable62pin-to-eps-8-pin-on-motherboard/1281416#1281416 . You should check your PSU manual for the correct sockets to use. https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Power-Supply-Units/Power-Supply-Units-Advanced/RMx-Series/p/CP-9020180-NA#tab-downloads

Comment: It may well be that all those connectors have the same pinout, and the swap is done by the cables and so long as you use the "PCIe" cables you will be fine. But it is your PSU manual that you should be trusting for that information, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: Sadly the manual doesn't explain what each of those are. I'm 100% sure I'm using the correct cables, they say "PCIe" & "CPU" right on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the manual should always be the first source of truth, all the plugs in question on the power supply are the same. And they are labeled as such, “6+2 PCIe & 4+4 CPU.” The lack of information specifying anything different in the manual suggests this is self explanatory.

What matters is that you use the provided CPU cable for the CPU and the provided PCIe cable for the GPU which should also be self explanatory as the two are not interchangeable unless forced.