# Adding power to my motherboard prevents it from starting

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I've been struggling with this computer for a while. I'm very comfortable with software, but hardware is not my strong suit.

The motherboard used here is an Asus TUF GAMING B560M-PLUS WIFI. I just realized that I had failed to plug in the second power input. Here's a picture of the motherboard components, with the two power inputs highlighted:

> [image: Motherboard power inputs]

Again, I had connected the power input marked as number 1 here, but not the one marked as number 2.

If only number 1 is connected, the computer starts, but there are absolutely no graphics from the CPU through the motherboard. Yes, the CPU supports graphics.

If *both* are connected, the computer does not start at all. The motherboard lights up somewhere, showing that the power supply works. But, unlike when only power input number 1 is present, the fan doesn't start and the "Power" button on the case doesn't light up after it's pressed.

There is a PC speaker on the motherboard. It beeps if there no memory DIMMs present, by which I mean it does beep when some errors are detected. It does not beep when that second power input is added.

What could this mean?

Comment: Best to check 1 part at a time. Unplug everything (GPU, any SATA drive, any m.2 drive), and just leave with CPU and RAM. If it boots and you can see the BIOS screen - start adding more parts. Also make sure your CPU is listed here https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B560M-PLUS-WIFI/HelpDesk_CPU/

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the right power connector. The EPS_12V connector looks similar to a PCIe power connector but the polarity is reversed and the keying may not necessarily prevent you from fitting one connector in the wrong slot. https://superuser.com/questions/1281414/ive-pluged-e-pci-power-cable62pin-to-eps-8-pin-on-motherboard/1281416#1281416

Comment: @Mokubai I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: @Mokubai You were absolutely right! I WAS using PCIe power! The writing that said it was very well hidden, but I finally found it. I tried power connectors marked CPU instead and those worked. Now, not only does the power switch light on, but if I keep it pressed when it's on, it turns off the computer, which it didn't before. That leads me to believe that maybe the BIOS may be working. Still no graphics from the CPU. But that's still a huge improvement. PLEASE, if you write your comment as answer, I could check it as correct. Thanks! I would never have found it on my own.

Comment: @eje211 it may be that something is damaged. Otherwise try resetting the CMOS, there's usually a jumper you short briefly while the system is powered down.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are using the right power connector.

The EPS_12V connector looks similar to a PCIe power connector but the polarity is reversed and the keying may not necessarily prevent you from fitting one connector in the wrong slot.

I've written before about this potential issue over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1281414/ive-pluged-e-pci-power-cable62pin-to-eps-8-pin-on-motherboard/1281416#1281416).

If it still doesn't power up with the correct connector then that would be concerning.  It may be that damage has been done somewhere and the board may need replacing.

You would hope that the PSU would detect a short across 12V and ground as would appear when the wrong connector is fitted, but it is not guaranteed.