# Confused about connecting PSU to MoBo

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have a Corsair RM650 and an AsRock A520M-ITX/A, but I'm a little confused as to which connector goes where.

I have recently been told that I need to connect both the AXT and the ATX12V connectors which is fine, but I'm not 100% sure which part of the PSU these should be going into.

**PSU back**

[image]

**Available cables that look correct**

- 24pin to split 18 & 10 pin

[image]

- 8 pin to 8 pin labelled CPU

[image]

I think my confusion stems from the MoBo user manual stating

> Please make sure that the power cable connected is for the CPU and not the graphics card. Do not plug the PCIe power cable to this connector

With regards to power connectors, the manual shows:

[image]

Comment: The 8 pin CPU connector looks worryingly similar to the 8-pin PCIe power connector for your GPU and have power on opposite pins. You can fry your GPU or motherboard surprisingly easily. https://superuser.com/questions/1281414/ive-pluged-e-pci-power-cable62pin-to-eps-8-pin-on-motherboard/1281416#1281416 They are also inadequately keyed to prevent you connecting them the wrong way and what keying might stop you could potentially be easily overcome with only moderate force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 8 pin CPU connector looks worryingly similar to the 8-pin PCIe power connector for your GPU and have power on opposite pins.

You can fry your GPU or motherboard surprisingly easily per my answer at (where there is a nice image showing connector keying and pinout) [I've pluged e-pci power cable(6+2pin) to eps 8 pin on motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1281414/ive-pluged-e-pci-power-cable62pin-to-eps-8-pin-on-motherboard/1281416#1281416)

They are also inadequately keyed to prevent you connecting them the wrong way and what keying might stop you could potentially be easily overcome with only moderate force.

Your PSU has a two PCIe/CPU outputs. Chances are that you have two cables, one marked PCIe and the other marked, as you have shown, CPU.

The pinout on the power supply side will be the same but the wires will go to different sides on the CPU or PCIe connector. The manual is telling you to make sure that the CPU connector goes to the motherboard and the PCIe one goes to your graphics card. Otherwise there is a good chance of letting all the magic smoke out of your motherboard, GPU and potentially the power supply as well.